# What lug pattern fits a 1994 Dodge Dakota?

Tags: wheels, lug-nut

I inherited my mom's 1994 Dodge Dakota after she passed.

She always wanted to fix it up. So in her honor, I plan to do that. Wheels are the most attractive upgrade for looks in my opinion and the factory wheels are really ugly.

However the bolt pattern is a weird 6 lug and I’m having trouble finding decent aftermarket rims. Any suggestions?

I am also considering a lift. Nothing huge. Probably a 2” lift. Recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The community can help you with identifying the lug pattern. The other questions are kinda shopping advice, so we can't answer those unfortunately. See [What kind of questions are not a good fit for this site?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1520/675)

Answer (score 1):

The PCD should be 6x114.3 with a centre bore of 71.66mm (some sites may knock off the .3 but its the same).

Most decent aftermarket wheel manufactures should be able to drill a custom bolt pattern as usually produce a run of wheels and then drill them to order, this saves them time and money and otherwise they would have to make thousands of wheels in different combinations of PCD and centre bore.

Nissan Navara, Pathfinder and the Xterra 2005-2010 on all use 6x114.3 but with a centre bore of 66.1, so it may be a better option to search for wheels for those vehicles and have the bore machined out. Any decent machinist or custom wheel specialist can do this.